# Try Catch exception is not catching the unhandled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, eto

I am building an app within an application called Rhino where it has a button to call this method.

```
public void AttachPopupToViewportWindow()
{
    _originalBound = Rhino.RhinoDoc.ActiveDoc.Views.ActiveView.Bounds;
    try
    {
        _formWindow = new SW.Win32Window(NativeHandle);
        General._viewportWindow.AddControl(_formWindow);
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex) 
    {
    }
}
```

When the method is called repeatedly in a very short time, the `NativeHandle` cannot be read anymore and it throws an Unhandled Exception.

[image]

The `NativeHandle` represents a `IntPtr` address to the WPF control.

I tried different ways of bypassing this exception. They all failed to work. Why hasn't the try-catch block catch the exception?

Comment: Do you have break on all exceptions turned on?

Comment: No. The exception simply wasn't caught. My suspicion is that it is an unhandled exception. That's why it is not caught.

Comment: Have you considered gating the processing with a bool flag? Set Is busy true at the start of the handler, false at the end. Exit the processing if IsBusy.